# Java compile errors when creating variables in a loop with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm learning Java on my own, currently learning arrays.
I tried practicing with something rather simple.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] names = {Max, Bella, Jack};
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        Dog dog[i] = new Dog();
        dog[i].name = names[i];
        System.out.println(dog[i].name);
    }
}

public static class Dog {
    public String name;
}
```

My idea was that it would create 3 dogs (dog0, dog1, and dog2) and then change dog0.name to Max, dog1.name to Bella, and dog3.name to Jack.

However, I'm getting the following compile errors:

```
/MyClass.java:6: error: ']' expected
        Dog dog[i] = new Dog();
                ^
/MyClass.java:6: error: illegal start of expression
        Dog dog[i] = new Dog();
                 ^
```

I just can't figure out, what's happening? The closing square bracket is right there, yet the compiler tells me it expects it, like it's absent. I'm probably doing the variables creation with arrays and loops wrong, if so, please point me out what's the right way.

P.S.: I'm sorry if it's a duplicate. That closing square bracket is the key point of my issue, and the search engine just ignores the ']', both here and in Google. I'm searching for threads about "expected ']'", but it only gives me the results for "expected".

**EDIT**: I probably didn't make myself clear enough. What I was trying to do is writing a code, that would be equal to the below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Dog dog0 = new Dog();
    dog0.name = "Max";
    Dog dog1 = new Dog();
    dog1.name = "Bella";
    Dog dog2 = new Dog();
    dog2.name = "Jack";
    }
}

public static class Dog {
    public String name;
}
```

Just tried to get the same results using arrays and loops, but failed.

Comment: What do you think `Dog dog[i]` means? Do you know how arrays are declared in Java?

Comment: @UnholySheep That means creating a link variable of a Dog class, and its name would be composed from the static part "dog" and a number of the current iteration of the loop.

Comment: Java does not support dynamic variable naming (and in nearly all cases that is a very bad idea anyway as it makes the code unmaintainable). Creating an array (or an `ArrayList` or maybe a `Map`) is the correct way to handle such cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to declare an Array of `Dog` outside of the Loop:

```
Dog[] dog = new Dog[names.length];
```

and set the value of a specific index inside the Loop:

```
dog[i] = new Dog();
```

So the main method Looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] names = {Max, Bella, Jack};
    Dog[] dog = new Dog[names.length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        dog[i] = new Dog();
        dog[i].name = names[i];
        System.out.println(dog[i].name);
    }
}
```

BTW: The properties of a class should not be public. So you should make Name private and add getter and setter to Access the property

**EDIT**
That can not be done in a loop and makes not much sense.

A better way is to create a constructor with Parameter Name so you can create the object and add set the Name property in one line:

```
public static class Dog {

   private String name;

   public Dog(String name){
       this.name = name
   }

   //getter and setter
   ....
}
```

So you can call it like:

```
Dog dog1 = new Dog("Max");
```

Comment: Got  the point about arrays declaration, thank you. But I don't want to create an array of dogs. I want just to create 3 objects of Dog class. Not to create an array of them. Is putting them in an array obligatory?

Comment: @AndyMac Then you have to create three different objects like dog1, dog2, doc3

Comment: @Jens exactly what I was trying to do. Just thought maybe I can do this with a loop and take names for them from an array of names.

Comment: @AndyMac No you can not make dynamic names. Also if you create it in a Loop, the Namespace is also in this Loop and it is not visible outside of the loop

Comment: @Jens I've edited the original post to explain my idea in a more clear way. AFAIR you're telling me this cannot be done in Java using arrays and loops. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

1) Declare Dog array out of the for loop.

```
Dog[] dog = new Dog[names.length];
```

2) Remove the Dog class name before setting the value of the index.

wrong:

```
Dog dog[i] = new Dog();
```

correct:

```
dog[i] = new Dog();
```

Comment: How will a compiler know this link variable is of Dog class then?

Comment: The class is already defined in the array creation. We don't have to define a second time the same class.